# Why AngularJs form.$invalid is true when form loads

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I have just started working on AngularJS and I am trying my hand at form validation. When I want to highlight the fields in red color when form.$invalid is true. All the fields on the form are required and that is the only validation possible.

Some fields have value selected when form is loaded,others do not have any initial value.

Now to give red highlighted color to required fields I do following:

```
 <form name="createForm" >
  <input type="text" name="name" ng-class="createForm.$invalid ? 'invalidaClass' : ''" required>

   ...
 </form>
```

Where invalidClass applies red color to required fields. however when i load the form all fields y default get red highlight color and has invalidClass applied. I also printed

```
     {{createForm.$invalid}}
```

property value when page loads and it is null. I would like to apply red highlight to fields only when there is no value in them. but not on load of the form. Is this a valid scenario what I am facing? What should be the correct way to do this?

```
   In Addition to this I would like to  show this error only when I click on one of the two buttons. How to achieve this?
```

Comment: try using pristine flag which is set when form or its input haven't been touched...

Comment: don't do `ng-class` / `createForm.$invalid`, angular provides you `ng-invalid` etc classes

Answer (score 1):

You're getting red border on required fields because of `HTML` validations by default provided by browser. You should use `novalidate` to tell the browser to not do any validation on default. Like

```
<form name="createForm"  novalidate>
```

After you should validate form data either using `ng-click` or `ng-submit` in your controller.

Comment: I have just provided relevent minimal info.

Answer (score 1):

Form validation using $pristine,

```
<form name="testForm" novalidate>
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : testForm.test.$invalid && !testForm.test.$pristine }">
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="test" id="txtPickUpPoint" name="test" required>
<p ng-show="testForm.test.$invalid && !testForm.test.$pristine" class="help-block">Error Message.</p>
</div>
</form>
```

It shows only when the form is invalid and will not show error on form load.

Comment: I tried this ..but as soon as you try typing something $pristine is set to false and as $invalid is true by default the condition is satisfied and it shows the color as highlighted. i want it to be applied only when I click on  a button and not when the page loads

Comment: So in that case on button click, you can apply ng-class to which ever element is invalid by checking '$invalid' on each element.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag when you click the submit button with `ng-click="submitClicked=true"`.

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'warning' : myForm.$invalid && submitClicked }" required>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="input1" required>
        <p ng-show="myForm.$invalid && submitClicked">Error Message.</p>
    </div>
<button type="submit" ng-click="submitClicked=true"></button>
</form>
```

Similarly you can use $dirty and $pristine for cases where your input area should be used or untouched, you can also use `ng-blur="some task"` to delegate tasks after the input area has lost focus. There is good explanation of most of the properties in [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation).

Answer (score 0):

The form is invalid on form load because of the required validator on input field. On form load the input field is empty therefore it's invalid.

You can achieve what you want by combining `form.$invalid` and another signal that is true only when user click submit button.